# Happy Jack-The Who lyrics

Tags: lyrics

It is mentioned in the Lyrics "Happy Jack wasn't old, but he was a man
He lived in the sand ***at*** the Isle of Man."

Isn't it supposed to be ***in*** the Isle of Man as it is a Crown dependency and should be treated nearly the same way as a country, like the phrases, I live in Egypt or I live in Australia?

Comment: Had you already noticed and discounted the many hits for [*“**at** the Isle of Man”*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22at+the+isle+of+man%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) that there are?

Comment: Do you mean the TT race?

Comment: Those are false positives. I don't understand why you mentioned it being a Crown dependency. Stopping in/on/at an isle/island doesn’t look at politics.

Comment: So correct English wise, it is supposed to be "in the Isle of Man", am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot imagine living in an island.

Comment: It is living "on" an island, but I'm using the word "in" here like when you say for example "I live in Cuba" and Cuba is an Island country so that's why.

Comment: Sorry, Daniel; songs are always poetry, never simple literature.

“(He)… lived in the sand at/in/on the Isle of Man" makes no useful difference to anything.

Even beyond that, please choose two or three very small islands - as clearly opposed to to Australia, the island continent - then tell us why you you insist you should not live “in” rather than “at” or “on” any of them.